# Problema URL Amigable con Htacess y php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, get

Tengo una página web donde estoy implementando un blog en PHP, pero antes de continuar, me gustaría dejar arregalado el tema de las URL AMIGABLES para el blog, no quiero que en el enlace sea 
**noticias.php?id=x**

Me gustaría conseguir la estructura de **noticias/titulo-noticia/**

Estoy haciendo algunas pruebas con HTTACCESS pero no consigo ningún resultado:

Código:

Botón que lleva a la noticia completa:

```
<a href="noticias.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <button>Leer más</button></a>
```

Ahora en noticias .php recibo esta ID con GET

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Y estoy jugando en el HTTACCESS con lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^noticias/(\w+)/?$ noticias.php?id=$30
```

El caso, es que aprobecho a preguntar: 
El "RewriteEngine on" ya lo tengo abierto más abajo para redireccionar la web a https, pasa algo si lo abro más veces? o solo debería estar abierto una?

Bueno, espero que alguien pueda conseguir ayudarme para conseguir estas URL para optimizar el SEO.

Comment: ¿`$30`? Eso parece un valor algo alto

Comment: Lo he arreglado de la siguiente manera:

Comment: Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/noticias.php?id=xxx" to "/noticias/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/noticias\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /noticias/%1? [R=301,L]

Comment: El caso es que ahora, he conseguido que me saque "noticias/31" pero no el titulo que es lo que me interesa, además pierdo los estilos :/